# border spacing issue with div table

Tags: html, css

I have created `div` table but got an issue with border spacing not perfect for me. I have tired border spacing border collapse separate border collapse but no luck.

Need: All border should be clean 1px. I just upload an example snapshot.

[image]

[jsfiddle.net/abilashu/w70a4ups/17/](https://jsfiddle.net/abilashu/w70a4ups/17/)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score -2):

use the border-collapse: collapse instead of separate.

```
 div.blueTable {
      border: 1px solid yellow;
      background-color: #848EA4 ;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: left;
      border-collapse:collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;

    }
```

Comment: You did not checked it with :)